# discrete response variable in python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a discrete response variable by transforming a column of dataset into binary output and make it a new column of dataset.

```
if dataset['column2'] > 1000 : 

   dataset['y2'] = 1

else :
   dataset['y2'] = 0
```

Comment: Ok, so what's the question?

Comment: What would be the actual question?

Comment: The error is : ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'column2': [998, 999, 1000, 1001, 1002]})
df['y2'] = df['column2'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x > 1000 else 0)
```

Result:

```
   column2  y2
0      998   0
1      999   0
2     1000   0
3     1001   1
4     1002   1
```

Answer (score -2):

In Italy we say you made a pasticcio!!